# Как при событии onclick в тэге, передать информацию о самом тэге?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем это выглядит вот так :

```
<div class="token_inner"><button type="button" class="close_l" onclick="close_l()">x</button></div>
<div class="token_inner"><button type="button" class="close_l" onclick="close_l()">x</button></div>
```

Вот, и я хочу чтобы при запуске функции close_l() была информация о тэге token_inner, то есть о родителе button'а, и когда я нажал на кнопку, то именно родитель того тэга на которого я нажал закрылся, а вторая кнопка так и была на месте. Как это сделать с помощью JS ?

//Кстати "о родителе баттона" звучит прикольно )**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function close_l(button) {
  var tokenInner = button.closest('.token_inner');
  if (tokenInner)
    tokenInner.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="token_inner">A<button type="button" class="close_l" onclick="close_l(this)">x</button></div>
<div class="token_inner">B<button type="button" class="close_l" onclick="close_l(this)">x</button></div>
```

> как вообще при нажатии удалить этот token_inner

```js
function close_l(button) {
  var tokenInner = button.closest('.token_inner');
  if (tokenInner)
    tokenInner.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="token_inner">A<button type="button" class="close_l" onclick="close_l(this)">x</button></div>
<div class="token_inner">B<button type="button" class="close_l" onclick="close_l(this)">x</button></div>
```

Comment: Круто, работает. Спасибки

Comment: @ПетяСальбич На здоровье. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Через 4 минуты, слушай а как вообще при нажатии удалить этот token_inner ?